# MD5 authentication on Google cloud using terraform

Tags: terraform

How to enable MD5 authentication for BGP session under cloud router using Terraform,
I know in terraform there is no provider or option to directly enable MD5 but i think there is a way to enable by using Null resource with a script(contains gcloud command to enable MD5 auth)